# How to view Flash and other videos on Linux systems?

Tags: fedora, firefox, adobe-flash

I'm running Fedora 17 and Firefox 12. When I navigate to some sites I'm unable to view videos because I'm missing some plugin. When I click 'installl missing plugin' I'm still not able to view the video.

Any idea I can view them without installing Flash Player (not Open Source I believe)? What directory are these web plugins stored?

Comment: Some Flash videos can't be viewed without the closed-source Flash Player. Chrome tends to be better at playing Flash out-of-the-box than Firefox.

Answer (score 3):

check this out: http://ask.fedoraproject.org/question/504/how-to-install-adobe-flash-for-fc16